# Какую нагрузку выдерживает mongodb?

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, highload, нагрузочное-тестирование

Задача хранить в nosql БД (монга для этого подходит больше всего, так как работаем с неструктурированным json) порядка 20 ТБ данных. Нагрузка предполагается до 20 rps. Количество документов порядка 4 млн. Каждый документ весит не более 10 мегабайт.

- Выдержит ли базюка?
- Сколько будут весить индексы по 5-10 полям?

Предполагается, что, в основном будут запросы по ключу. Также предполагаются несложные запросы-фильтры по некоторым полям. Глубина вложения 4-6 уровней.

Монге отдаю предпотчтение, так как я знаю это БД лучше других